# Get the status of an ongoing, outgoing Twilio call

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have the following currently:

```
twilio.calls
  .create({
    url: process.env.TWILIO_OUTGOING_XML,
    to: currentNumber,
    from: process.env.TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER
  })
  .then(function (call) {
    while (true) {
      getCallStatus(call);
    }
  });

function getCallStatus(x) {
  twilio.calls(x)
    .fetch()
    .then(call => console.log(call.status));
}
```

However, with the while loop in place it will not output the status of the call. When I remove the while loop, the status is logged to the console, *but* it only shows `queued` as naturally it is only getting the status once, at the initial creation. So, how can I ensure I am always getting the latest status of the call available?

Comment: You can also use the Twilio CLI with the watch plug-in, if you want to see this in near realtime, Five Twilio CLI features you should know about - https://www.twilio.com/blog/five-twilio-cli-features-you-should-know-about "Watch all your notifications right in the CLI (@twilio-labs/plugin-watch)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa...That method of determining the call status is a bit too intense on your callstack and server resources. Definitely not very scalable-- can you imagine if you were serving hundreds, if not, thousands of calls?

You should look into statusCallBackEvents. They provide you a way to monitor the state of your call by adding 2 additional properties, one with your endpoint to receive the status updates and the other to specify the events you want to keep track of. It is much less resource intensive than the way you described, and it is the intended use case for such a task.

Example:

```
twilio.calls
  .create({
    statusCallback: `https://${YOUR_API_ENDPOINT}/events`,
    statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'answered', ...],
    statusCallback: 'POST',
    url: process.env.TWILIO_OUTGOING_XML,
    to: currentNumber,
    from: process.env.TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER
  })
```

You're basically creating a Pub/Sub relationship between Twilio(Pub) and your  server/lambda/whatever(Sub), instructing Twilio to send the specified call status events to your endpoint you supplied. Now all your route has to do is handle any of the events Twilio sends your way.

This is a much cleaner solution. You'll probably end up saving yourself hours upon *hours* of debugging race conditions and other unwanted *things*...

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will "lock" all your code commands, it fill full the stack of JS engine, this mean `twilio.calls(x)` has been executed but `console.log(call.status)` never been call (js engine keeps the command execute in a queue forever).

Change while loop to a asynchronous action like `setInterval`:

```js
twilio.calls
  .create({
    url: process.env.TWILIO_OUTGOING_XML,
    to: currentNumber,
    from: process.env.TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER
  })
  .then(function (call) {
    setInterval(function() {
      getCallStatus(call);
    }, 1000); // check call status every second
  });

function getCallStatus(x) {
  twilio.calls(x)
    .fetch()
    .then(call => console.log(call.status));
}
```